# Link to a specific part of a webpage, if the author didn't create #named anchors within it?

Tags: browser, html

I use named anchors as section links all the time, and it drives me nuts when  I find a good resource on the web, but it's part of a longer page, and there are no anchors.

I want to send someone a link to "read this!", but it feels awkward saying "Read this, after you open the page hit ctrl-F and search for 'multiple messages' and that's the paragraph."

Is there a way to force the target of a link to jump to a particular part of the page, despite the author's omission?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can link to any text on any page using the general form:
`https://domian.com/page.html#:~:text=some%20phrase`

Comment: That works! Only works in Chrome, but that's an 80% solution and perhaps other browsers will pick it up someday. Beautifully simple, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the page if this is possible. The anchors are defined as `id`s within the source of a page. Even if the author did not provide links to sections, there might be some `id`s present at the page's source, which could be used as anchors. Let me explain through an example:

1. Open the page you want to link to, e.g. `https://superuser.com/questions/1488963/`.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to view it's source.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and search for `_id="` (Replace the *underscore* by a *space*!), see example below:
   [image]
4. Any `id` can be used as a jump target. Search for one that is near to the section you want to link to, e.g. `question`.
5. Craft the link by appending `#ID` to the page's URL: `https://superuser.com/questions/1488963/#question`

[Click here](https://superuser.com/questions/1488963/#question) to try the example. However, if there are no `id`'s, it is not possible.